# Error in strinverse function for reversing strings

Tags: c

I wrote the following function to inverse a string `s`

```
char *strinverse( const char *s ){
    char *t;
    int i = 0;
    while (*s) {
        s++;
        i++;
    }
    while (i >= 0){
        s--;
        *t = *s;
        t++;
        i--;
    }
    *t = '\0';
    return t;
}

int main(void){

    char v[4]="abc";
    char r[4];
    char *pr = r;

    pr = strinverse(v);
    printf("%s", pr);
    return 0;

}
```

The idea is to find out the length of the string `s` in the first while-loop, then to decrease the pointer of `s` while copying the respective values into `t`. For some reason the program crashes and the compiler gives me no information. Maybe there's something wrong in the main function? Thanks for your advices!

Comment: You have not allocated any space for new string! `char *t` doens't have any memory space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer edited

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *strinverse(const char *s ){
  char *t, *p;
  int i = 0;
  while (*s) {
    s++;
    i++;
  }
  t = (char*)malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(char)); //added this!
  p = t;
  while (i >= 0){
    s--;
    *t = *s;
    t++;
    i--;
  }
  *t = '\0';
  return p;
}

int main(void){

  char v[4]="abc";
  char *pr;

  pr = strinverse(v);
  printf("%s\n", pr);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Now the program runs, doesn't return the correct value though. Seems like my printf doesn't do anything..

Comment: have you noticed the `(i + 1)` in malloc? that `+1` is meant to store `/0` so that `printf` can work!

Comment: Yes, I noticed that (I didn't downvote by the way!). Still printf doesn't seem to print anything.

Comment: This is a bad example. Because you are using malloc, you have to free the pointer in the end, but you modify the pointer t, so the `malloc`ed pointer is changed to the `\0` of the allocated string.

Comment: I downvoted, because your answer is completely wrong, you obviously did not test it and did not make any effort in writing this answer.

Comment: @Gandaro I have edited the answer. I accept that I didn't try to actually compile and run the previous answer but I just wanted to show that `malloc` was missing!

Comment: Oh great, now it works :) Could you explain why we need the new pointer p?

Comment: At the end you have `*t = '\0'`. At this point of time t is pointing to last position of your `malloce`d array! you need to return the first position! previously it was returning the last position of the array!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that program crashes is that you have not allocated space for pointer `t`. In this case your program invokes undefined behavior. Allocate space for `t`

```
 t = malloc(i + 1);
```

Do not forget to free memory at the end using `free(t)`.

Comment: Using `malloc` is not a good approach in my opinion. Rather specify a pointer as parameter in which the new string will be written, or modify the string inplace.

Comment: Problem is that I have to use ´const char *s´ as function parameter

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function that changes the string in-place instead.

```
void reversestr(char *s)
{
        char tmp;
        size_t i, len = strlen(s);

        for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
                tmp = s[i];
                s[i] = s[len - 1 - i];
                s[len - 1 - i] = tmp;
        }
        s[len] = '\0';
}
```

If you need the reversed string separately, you can just use `strdup` before you call `reversestr`. BTW: function names that start with "str" are reserved for functions of the C standard library.

Comment: Thank you :) This also works. I forgot to mention that I was not allowed to use `string.h` (so `strlen(s)` wouldn't have worked for me).

Comment: Ugly homework restriction.  Anyway you should be smart enough to implement your own "strlen".

Comment: If this was your homework, I recommend you to at least modify my answer to not use strlen, as you actually don't have to count the characters in before, it is just easier.

Answer (score 0):

you have not make malloc in the pointer "t" and you have problem in this line "*t = *s;"